# Does it make sense for server to return Authorization header

Tags: http, http-headers

I will admit I am not a very good backend developer but I was doing some research about the `Authorization` header. It seems pretty straight-forward and even packages like https://github.com/jshttp/basic-auth I understand.

In our Spring application though, we are returning the header `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=`. Does this make sense to do this? The Client wouldn't care about this correct?

Comment: No, as a response header that makes no sense AFAIK.

Comment: @CBroe thank you this was just more of a clarification so I will probably remove this question. I can't use IRC at work for simple things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense.  Since the client knows it already (since it sent it in the first place) sending it back is a waste of time.

Comment: So "No" -- it doesn't make sense. Thank you.

Comment: I was answering the "The Client wouldn't care about this correct?" question, but I'll change it to answer the title.

Comment: Ah sorry! Didn't realize my own question was misworded like that.

Comment: @adam-beck  I should have put "No, no, yes". :)  There's no reason to delete the question; others will probably find it useful.